# is it posible to create mulitple attribute in one attribute set for configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two attributes.

- Color
- Size

My **attribute set** name is red.I have added the sizes in my **configurable product**, but when i try to add the color in **Associated products**, it shows the error which is shown below:

[image]

Even after set the **scope** field as ***Global***
How to rectify this?I'm completely new to Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you can get your answer on this link :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/298161/

Comment: but I'm not clearly understood that!

Comment: Look, after adding products with different combinations like:
1)red + small
2)red + large
these products will be added with unique slug.
you can not make other combination of red+small.

get it?

Comment: i didnot add the red + small combination before this.Then why its showing like this @kishore Thanth

Comment: How can i edit the already created attribute set for multiple attribute @kishore Thanth